# View is getting inflated everytime in getView. findViewById(...) is done many times. I have used View Holder

Tags: android, android-view

```
public View getView(final int pos, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    View view = arg1;

    if (arg1 == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        System.out.println("Inflating view");
        arg1 = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.inflatefreedownlod, arg2, false);
        holder.im = (ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.imf1);
        holder.tv1 = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tvf1);
        holder.tv2 = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.mini1);
        holder.tv3 = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.m1);
        arg1.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) arg1.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv1.setText(NAME.get(pos).toString());
    holder.tv2.setText(contentName.get(pos).toString());
    holder.tv3.setText(minidescp.get(pos).toString());
    URL url1;

    try {

        url1 = new URL(imurl.get(pos).toString());
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url1.openConnection().getInputStream());
        holder.im.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        //bmp.recycle();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    arg1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0; i < NAME.size(); i++)
                if (pos == i) {
                    getFreeContent(Cid.get(pos).toString(), Vid.get(pos).toString(), contentName.get(pos).toString());
                }

        }

    });

    return arg1;
}
```

I see the logcat which shows Inflating View 3 times. I have 3 LinearLayout displayed in listview when i test it on emulator. Why is my view null everytime?. View also is inflated every time. Anything wrong with my code

Comment: Your inflating your View to as a ViewGroup. I think you should inflate it by just using inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflatefreedownlod, null);

Comment: about how many items do you have in the list?

Comment: 3 list items each with imageview and 3 textviews. @Slickelito i will try ur idea. Thanks

Comment: Slickelito I am facing the same problem. I have tried your idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have three items in your list, and there is space on the screen for three rows in your `ListView`, `getView()` will be called three times with a `null` `View` to create those three rows. You cannot recycle a row that is presently in use.

Comment: ok. Does this effect performance by causing garbage collection. Garbage collection is called between getview calls. After 2 view inflates gc is called. What is the problem??

Comment: @RaghunandanK: You are downloading images from the Internet on the main application thread -- that is a lot of work that will generate garbage. It also is work that should **not** be done on the main application thread.