# CustomAdapter getView() is called every time while scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, custom-adapter

The `getView()` method in my `CustomAdapter` is called every time I scroll up or down.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.projectlist, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.projectTitelTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectTitle);
        holder.projectInfoTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectInfo);
        holder.projectImageImageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectImage);
        holder.projectDeadline = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectdeadline);

        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }
    if (projectItems.size() <= 0) {
        [...]
    } else {
         [...]
        }
    }
    return vi;
}
```

The `ListView` XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Why it is called every time I scroll up or down?
Assuming, I have 10 Items displayed. If I scroll down, the `getView()` called one time and it show me one more Item. If I hard scroll and want to go to the end of the list. It get called multiple times until the data is loaded and displayed.

If I want to scroll then up, the same scenario happens.

What can I do to prevent calling multiple times `getView()` or is it necessary?

Kind Regards

Comment: It's normal behaviour of ListView adapter to call getView() method multiple times

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648995/view-is-getting-inflated-everytime-in-getview-findviewbyid-is-done-many-ti if it helps

Comment: thank you! I didn't know that!

Comment: on scroll ListView, for every item, getView() is called which returns a view for your ListView Item. Its the default feature which is awesome but have to maintain values based on position of item in ListView get in getView() method whenever you scroll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how ListAdapters work. `getView()` is used whenever a new list item needs to be created, or at least when a list item needs to be updated with data for a particular position.

Comment: Thank you for explanation of the method!

Answer (score 0):

As Suggested by [RomainGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy)

> This is not an issue, there is absolutely no guarantee on the order in
>   which getView() will be called nor how many times.

It's normal behaviour of ListView adapter to call getView() method multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

If it is not necessaire to change something if you scroll you coud try something like that.

```
boolean fisttime = true;
```

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
if(position == 0 && isFirstRun) {
    View vi = convertView;
ViewHolder holder;
if (convertView == null) {
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.projectlist, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.projectTitelTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectTitle);
    holder.projectInfoTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectInfo);
    holder.projectImageImageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectImage);
    holder.projectDeadline = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectdeadline);

    vi.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
}
if (projectItems.size() <= 0) {
    [...]
} else {
     [...]
    }
}
return vi;
}
```

}