# Android ListView Custom Adapter

Tags: android

My question is very simple: i have a Custom adapter that sets image in a listview:

```
package com.tred.stars;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public static String selected_pers= "Graziana Grasso";
Activity context;
String[] itemname;
Integer[] imgid;


public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;

}




public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {

    String[] description ={
            "desc",
            "desc",
            "desc",
            "desc",
            "desc",
            "desc",
            "desc",
            "desc"
    };

    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null, true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pers_name);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pers_image);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pers_comment);
    LinearLayout llrow = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), selected_pers, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (getItem(position).toString()==selected_pers){
        llrow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#29A3CC"));
    }

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    extratxt.setText(description[position]);
    return rowView;

};
```

}

And in my activity i set the adapter to my listview:

```
 DrawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerLW);
    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
    DrawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But when i run the application the method getView in CustomListAdaper seems to repeat itself continously and the variable *selected_pers* seems to be null.

Comment: Which line is failing? Like which selected_pers is null

Comment: getView will get called many times. thats fine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648995/view-is-getting-inflated-everytime-in-getview-findviewbyid-is-done-many-ti

Comment: try like this `itemname[position].toString() == selected_pers`

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null, true);
```

To:

```
mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);
```

And you can not use `==` when comparing strings. Change this line:

```
if (getItem(position).toString()==selected_pers)
```

To:

```
if (getItem(position).toString().equals(selected_pers))
```

Also, take a look at [this example](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) to learn how to implement correct & efficient ListView.